# top cannot be resolved in a stack

Tags: java, stack

Given this code in Java:

```
import java.util.*;


public class StackLab {

 int top;

 int[] array;

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

   Stack s = new Stack();

   initStack(s);

   push(s, 8);

   peek(s);

 }

 public static void initStack(Stack s)
 {

  s.top = -1;

  s.array = new int[100];

 }

 public static void push(Stack s, int v)
 {

  s.top++;

  s.array[s.top] = v; 

 }

 public static int peek(Stack s)
 {

  return s.array[s.top];

 }

 public static void pop(Stack s)
 {

  s.top--;

 }

 public static boolean isEmpty(Stack s)
 {

  return s.top == -1;

 }

}
```

I get an error that top and array cannot be resolved or is not a field. I don't understand why that error is popping up. I have declared top and array at the beginning, before main. Would someone please explain to me how I should change this declaration? All I want is to perform basic Stack interactions (push, pop, peek, isEmpty), but I've already hit the wall because I can't see what's wrong with my code/declarations of variables. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
Stack s = new Stack();
```

should be

```
StackLab s = new StackLab();
```

All your method parameters should be of type `StackLab` rather than `Stack` as well.

`Stack` is `java.util.Stack` and doesn't have any visible fields.